# Automatically resize d3.js chart y scale based on brush selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js v4.

Is there a more convenient way to find the minimum and maximum values of a brush selection. This is meant to resize the y axis when I select a period in my brush area below.

Here is my method (everything is inside my function called when the brush is used) :

- I find the extent limits of my selection

  ```
  extent = d3.event.selection.map(chartComponent.x2().invert))
  ```
- Then I have to redo an array containing all my selected points: I go on each point and compare it to the extent[0] or extent[1] to see if it is in the limits. I store the beginning and end point indices and then I use data.slice(begin, end) on my original data to get a new array.
- Then apply d3.min and d3.max on the new array to find the min and the max level.
- Then set the y axis to use theses limits.

  ```
  chart.y().domain([chartComponent.ymin, chartComponent.ymax]);
  chart.yaxisGraph.call(chartComponent.yAxis(true));
  ```

Do someone have a better idea ?

Comment: As no on left an answer I've implemented my solution. This solution has acceptable performances so I'll stick with it. If you have a better idea feel free to leave a comment or answer, I'm still looking for something better.